# How to split a 6 or 7 GB file into several sub-2 GB files without splitting entry?

Tags: command-line, files, split

My level has 6 to 10 GB sized files as input. These files contain several lines of data. The next level's max input capacity is 2GB. So I have to split these 6-10 GB files into several sub-2 GB files without breaking lines! Basically I have to split a file based on size but without breaking lines.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't have any lines longer than 2GB, you can use

```
split --line-bytes=2GB
```

From the info manual:

```
‘--line-bytes=SIZE’
 Put into each output file as many complete lines of INPUT as
 possible without exceeding SIZE bytes.  Individual lines or records
 longer than SIZE bytes are broken into multiple files.
```

Comment: `split` on OSx does not support this parameter :(

Answer (score 2):

I believe this will provide almost what you need

`split -n`

```
-n, --number=CHUNKS
              generate CHUNKS output files.


CHUNKS may be: 
N       split into N files based on size of input
K/N     output Kth of N to stdout
l/N     split into N files without splitting lines
l/K/N   output Kth of N to stdout without splitting lines
r/N     like 'l' but use round robin distribution
r/K/N   likewise but only output Kth of N to stdout
```